# with_index in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

I upgraded to

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553)
```

Any idea why I get

```
ArgumentError in Territories#show

Showing /home/Thomas/territory_management/app/views/territories/show.html.erb where line #24 raised:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Extracted source (around line #24):

24:     <% @addresses.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |address, index| %>
```

According to the doc: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index if should work just fine. What am I missing?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the version of Ruby you think you are? Might there be a `.rvmrc` in the directory you're doing this from? It works fine for me:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
pry(main)> users = User.limit(5)
pry(main)> users.to_enum.with_index(5).each { |ex, i| puts "#{i}: #{ex.name}" }
5: Dave
6: Nick
7: Keenan
8: Hater
9: Greg
```

Comment: It says I am, but it behaves as I am not...

$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i386-cygwin]

$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
irb(main):001:0> users = User.limit(5)
NameError: uninitialized constant User
        from (irb):1
irb(main):004:0> users.to_enum.with_index(5).each { |ex, i| puts "#{i}: #{ex.na
me}" }
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
        from (irb):4:in `with_index'
        from (irb):4

Comment: Huh. I don't see how that's possible. Unfortunately, my incredulousness doesn't help you ;)

Comment: I seems that something was wrong with my installation. It's working now. Thanks.

Comment: *whew* That would have been weird otherwise ;) Glad you worked it out.

Comment: I have one additional question here though. Why is this thing one item to far? When I do <% @addresses.to_enum.with_index(1).each do |address, index| %> and I have 9 addresses in the hash, I get 10 rows...

Comment: I'm a little skeptical of that, are you sure?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3573/discussion-between-thomas-and-dave-newton)